# AngularJS - need to highlight and unhighlight the selected choice in different pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<li class="cursorPointer" ng-repeat="inner in outer.inners | orderBy: 'id' " ng-class="{selected: inner.id === idSelectedinner }">
<img src="{{inner.icon}}" alt="{{inner.description}}" title="   {{inner.description}}"  ng-dblclick="saveData($parent.outer,inner,$parent.$index)"/>


 $scope.idSelectedinner = null;
 $scope.idSelectedinner = inner.id;
```

I have a multiple outer question and displaying inner question per page and onselecting single answer, I am highlighting the selected answer. The problem is if select second questions answer,my first questions selected answer is also deselected. Please let me know how to keep the selected answers throughout the pages.

Comment: A plunker would help us debug here. please be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, the `outer` is a question and `inner` is answers, and you have multiple questions. You should add `selected` property to `outer` and set it by clicking question. And in question you can add something like:

```
ng-class="selected: $index == outer.selected"
```

Here is a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/NtEOkm35dYLuJR6jSWpp?p=preview

**I've updated the plunker. Now with paging**

The paging doesn't matter, if you store selected values in model.

Comment: I need to select the inner images where they are the muliple options, where I need to select the inner image should highlight which image option is choosed. The problem is if i select a image among 4 one is highlighted in first question but if I select second questions, one image the first questions selected image is  deselected and only second is selected

Comment: Yes, it's because you storing the selected image in a single scope variable, and when you pick image in second question it's overwriting your first selection. Look at my plunker. You should store selected items in model.

Comment: I agree , that is the problem but I need to keep the selected for throughout the pages please let me know how to implement and I am new to angular.

Comment: Check the Plunker. I've added everything you need.

Comment: You don't need setData() method. Just set `selected` property on click. You can get all selected values on form submit. I can't guide you. You just need to rethink your solution based on mine.

Comment: I am not an expert like you. I will modify based on your solution. Thanks

Comment: @user3428736, i'm not expert as well. :) Just have a little more experience. Feel free to ask more questions, but be a little more specific. I'll gladly help you. :)